# mysql : make mysql db to be case sensitive for queries

Tags: mysql

In my  mysql db, i have a table called `customer`

In my local test environment  mysql db, I can do `select * from Customer`       but when my code is rolled out to a production environment for clients to use,  `select * from customer` throws syntax error.

This is because the production environment mysql db is case  sensitive.

How do i change my local enviorement mysql to be case sensitive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add  (or change)    this system variable to the bottom of my.ini and restart mysql:

my.ini:

lower_case_table_names=2

> lower_case_table_names  2
>
> Table and database names are stored on disk using the lettercase
>   specified in the CREATE TABLE or CREATE DATABASE statement, but MySQL
>   converts them to lowercase on lookup. Name comparisons are not case
>   sensitive. This works only on file systems that are not
>   case-sensitive! InnoDB table names are stored in lowercase, as for
>   lower_case_table_names=1.